# Drawing artifacts when drawing a NSString in a NSButton

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, drawrect, nsimage, nsbutton

I am using `drawRect` to draw a NSString inside a custom view, which is a subview of `NSButton`. The `drawRect` of the NSButton is also drawing an `NSImage`, which appears to the be the problem. If I remove the `drawRect` code for the `NSImage`, it no longer happens (but then I don't have a background).

Here is the custom view `drawRect` (shortened):

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    let string: NSString = NSString(string: thermostat.displayTargetTemperature())
    string.drawAtPoint(NSMakePoint(CGFloat(width), CGFloat(y)), withAttributes: self.attributes)

}
```

Here is the `NSButton` `drawRect`:

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    var image = NSImage(named: FILDarkManager.enabled ? "preferences-statusbar-bg-dark" : "preferences-statusbar-bg-light")

    if (self.state == NSOnState) {
        image?.drawInRect(dirtyRect, fromRect: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1.0, respectFlipped: true, hints: nil)
    }
    else {
        image?.drawInRect(dirtyRect, fromRect: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 0.8, respectFlipped: true, hints: nil)
    }

    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
}
```

Perhaps it is something to do with the operation when drawing the `NSImage`?

The strange thing is that if I hover over the view, it draws correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing the image into [self bounds] rather than into dirtyRect.

Drawing the string probably dirties part of your button, causing your code to draw the image into that dirtyRect.